# Trying to remove a space from a string in Swift, get compile error

Tags: ios, string, swift

I'm trying to eliminate a space from a string if there is one, and my code looks like this:

```
func removeSpaceFromString(cityString: NSString) ->String {
        var cityWOSpace: String = ""
        if cityString.rangeOfString(" ") != nil {

            cityWOSpace = cityString.stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString(" ", withString:"", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

        return cityWOSpace
        }
    }
```

However, with the if statement in there I get the compile error that `cannot invoke '!=' with an argument of list type...` and if I remove the if statement then I get an error that `NSString does not have a member named 'stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString'` which occurs whether the string is a String or an NSString.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `rangeOfString` not return optional so you cannot check with `nil`.You should check `NSNotFound` for location of `NSRange`.Also there is another errror in code `range` in  `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` can not be `nil` as it is not optional

```
func removeSpaceFromString(cityString: NSString) ->String {
  var cityWOSpace: String = ""
  if cityString.rangeOfString(" ").location != NSNotFound {

  cityWOSpace = cityString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, cityString.length))

  return cityWOSpace
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for actually answering my question instead of just pointing me to the docs like I didn't know they were there. If I knew what I was trying to do I wouldn't be on here anyways.

Comment: you can also replace (cityString: NSString) with (cityString: String)

Answer (score 1):

The docs on `rangeOfString` are here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:

Read them. That is what they are for.

It returns an NSRange, not an NSRange wrapped in an Optional. `rangeOfString` will never return nil. So it is illegal compare it to nil.

It will return a zero-length range if it can't find the string.

Comment: Okay then how would I check to see if the space character is in the string? And the other issue still remains in that `String does not have a member named 'stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString'`

Comment: @PatrickBush: You have a typo, it is stringByReplacingOccur***r***encesOfString ...